# Unexpected HTTP/1.x Request Errors with Login Pages

Tags: java, exception, grpc

I have a Java GRPC server and I am getting unwanted HTTP/1.x requests. It is crowding the log files because it keep throwing exceptions. I want the service to peacefully ignore those message. How would I make the server ignore those messages?

I work at a big company so I can't stop the logging nor the messages.

I was wondering whether an interceptor might work.